# String.equals is not a function in Web Worker

Tags: javascript, string, string-comparison, web-worker

I am converting a table that was previously working but locking the UI during some tasks to be managed by a web worker. One of the functions I am updating is sorting. My old Sort function has been converted to:

```
function mySort(column){
    myWorker.postMessage({ message: "sort", column: column.id });
}
```

In my worker:

```
self.onmessage = function (e) {
    switch (e.data.message) {
        case "sort":
            DoSort(e.data.column);
            break;
    }
}

var m_sortCol;
function DoSort(column) {
    if (m_sortCol != null && column.equals(m_sortCol)) // <---- The problem is here
        myData.reverse();
    else {
        m_sortCol = column;
        myData.sort(column);
    }
}
```

The problem is, when my worker gets to the indicated line, it throws an exception, `column.equals is not a function.` Looking at the data in the Debugger, both `column` and `m_sortCol` have values, and they sure look like strings, though I don't see anywhere the object type is explicitly stated. I have tried changing the statement to `column.toString().equals(m_sortCol.toString())`, and the exception changes to `column.toString(...).equals is not a function.`

This code previously worked before changing to a web worker. Could the web worker be messing with my types somehow so that what looks like a string isn't actually a string? Or could the worker not have access to String functions somehow? My research says web workers should have String functions, but I am at a loss for how to explain this.

Comment: [String values don't have an `equals` method, anywhere](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Instance_methods). What's the value of `column` before you move it to a worker?

Comment: If you're comparing strings, use `===`.

Comment: Strings are a primitive in Javascript, so you can just use `==` (or `===`)

Comment: Well, now that I look back at my sources, I see that the article https://fluentthemes.com/compare-strings-correctly-javascript/ seems to be flip-flopping back and forth between saying Java and Javascript. All the other links I have correctly say Java despite my search having been for Javascript. So that's frustrating.

Comment: This does raise the question of why it was previously working, though.

Comment: Where does the data originally comes from? Is it sent to the worker through postMessage? In that case, what is the prototype of said `column` before it's sent to the worker? postMessage can't pass custom class's protos.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your string prototype has been modified, since there is no .equals function on the standard Javascript string type. In this case, you should simply be using == or ===. (This is an example of why modification of the string prototype is considered bad form in Javascript).